# Access path document's data when multiple path variables are present

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm building a small chat app to polish up my Android/Firebase skills.
But I ran into a problem regarding document access.
The path to documents I wish to protect is the following
`chat/{chat_id}/messages/{message_id}`.

In order for a user to read or write a new `message`, they need to be authorised, meaning `request.auth != null`.
But also, I want only the users which are members of the given chat to be able to read/write messages.

In the `{chat_id}` document, I have a `List` field, which contains the `uid`'s of all users which are currently members of that chat. So in order for the user to access messages, I need to verify that their uid exists within the `{chat_id}.data.members` list.
Is there currently a way to access the `{chat_id}` document from the messages rule? 
If I do `resource.data`, it gives me a `message` object, which I don't need, because it doesn't contain any important data. 
 
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Answer to your concrete question below. If that doesn't allow you to fix your problem, edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone data+rules+code with which any of us can reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any variable path segments (also referred to as `wildcards` in the Firestore documentation) for the current document/collection upwards.

For example, have a look at the Firebase documentation example of [accessing other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents), which has:

```
allow create: if request.auth != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid))
```

In here `$(database)` is the name of the containing database, as declared in a parent match statement.

In your example, you have access to `$(chat_id )` and `$(message_id)` from the path you've shown in your question, and for example `$(database)` from an outer match statement, and the `$request` and `$resource` built-in global variables.

Comment: So if I were to try and check if a document with key = `request.auth.uid` exists under a `members` collection on the path `chatRooms/{chatroom_id}/members/{member_id}`, I would do: `exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/chatRooms/$(resource.data.chatRoomID)/members/$(request.auth.uid))`?

Comment: Yes I know that, been in a bit of a rush today so I forgot :)